Attributes showing as pop up table but not present in description field, I need to use this KMZ with attributes in QGIS
Ok so firstly, the issue started coming up when I wanted to use the kmz with another layer in QGIS 3.40.1. I troubleshooted other issues as well related to the same kmz files, and I found out that in order to be able to see the attributes in QGIS using kmz or shapefile, the attributes must be present in the source file which then needs to be extracted.
The main problem is that in the source kmz file, I have polygons, and when I click on these polygons a table with attributes popup, but there is nothing present in the description field (Right click>Properties) of these polygons.
I have found that in order to use the attributes from kmz, we need to convert html to attributes using the GIS softwares, but there is no html data, just the table popup when I click on the polygons in google earth.
How can I extract the attribute data from kmz file?

The attribute are in the attribute table not in the layer properties. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#working-with-the-attribute-table

Use KML Tools plugin to extract attributes from html.

You may also export your .kmz file into either .gpkg or .shp file.
